# How can i insert my cart items to database?

Tags: php, html

i have already database named myDatabase the form that i created already can insert to database but when im tryng to insert my cart items it didnt work please help me. How should i insert the items that been added by the user?

form.php

```html
<?php
session_start();




if (!isset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'])){ $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] = array(); }


//Add an item only if we have the threee required pices of information: name, price, qty
if (isset($_GET['add']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['qty'])){
 //Adding an Item
 //Store it in a Array
 $ITEM = array(
  //Item name  
  'item_name' => $_GET['add'], 
  //Item Price
  'price' => $_GET['price'], 
  //Qty wanted of item
  'qty' => $_GET['qty']  
  );

 //Add this item to the shopping cart
 $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][] =  $ITEM;
 //Clear the URL variables
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
else if (isset($_GET['remove'])){
 //Remove the item from the cart
 unset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][$_GET['remove']]);
 //Re-organize the cart
 //array_unshift ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'], array_shift ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']));
 //Clear the URL variables
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

} 



// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";
$item="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }
    
  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }
  
  if (isset($_POST["item_name"])) {
    $item = "";
  } else {
    $item = test_input($_POST["item_name"]);
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
<style>
#shoppingCartDisplay {
 margin:5cm 0cm 0cm 17cm;
 
}
#pageHeader {
 margin:0cm 0cm 0cm 20m;
}
</style>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation </title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="form1">
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<h1> Order Form </h1>
<h3> Please Fill Up this Form for Reservation </h3>
<p><span class="error">Your email address will not be published Required fields are marked(*).</span></p>
<h4> First_Name: </h4>
<input type="text" name="first_name">
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
 
<h4> Last_Name: </h4>
<input type="text" name="last_name">
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<h4> E-mail:</h4>
<input type="text" name="email">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>

<h4> Comment </h4>
<textarea name ="comment" rows="8" cols="80">  </textarea>
<br><input type="Submit" class="submit" value="Submit Form">



<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"></form>
 <form action="home.html">
    <input type="submit"  class="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
</form>
</div>

</form>



<div id="shoppingCartDisplay">
<form action="process.php" method="POST" name="shoppingcart">
 <?php 
    //We want to include the shopping cart in the email
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <table width="500" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Cost</th>
      </tr>
    
        <?php 
        //Print all the items in the shopping cart
        foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
        ?>
        <tr id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">    
            <td><a href="?remove=<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">remove</a></td>
            <td><?php echo $item ['item_name'];  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
            <td><input name="items_qty[<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>]" type="text" id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>_qty" value="<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="3" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['qty'] * $item['price']; ?></td>  
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$item.'">   
        </tr>
        <?php
 

        }
        ?>
    </table>
 <?php $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART_HTML'] = ob_get_flush(); ?>





</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```html
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
 
<?php




 
// create a variable
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$item=$_POST['item_name'];
//Execute the query
 
 
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO employees1 (first_name,last_name,email,comment,item_name)
          VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$comment','$item')");
    
      

  
      
    
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0){
 echo "<p>Form Submitted</p>";
 echo "<a href=\"form.php\">Go Back</a>";
} else {
 echo "RESERVATION FAILED<br />";
 echo mysqli_error ($connect);
}
```

Comment: the error was Notice: Undefined index: item_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\modal\process.php on line 15

Comment: please only post the relevant code